# OpenCV 3.0 - SVM + HOG gives same wrong responses for half-person detection

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, detection

I'm working in a detector for half bodies, in order to improve the performance of a normal people detector. I know there are more ways to deal with occlusion but this is what i was asked for to do in my end of degree project. My problem is that I'm not getting a good performance, more over, I'm getting kind a pattern in wich 4 rectangles that represent the detections are shown in almost the same position, not even representing a half body.

I have a set of images with 414 images of top-half bodies cropped by myself, used as positive samples, and 8520 negative images. All of them sized 64x64. I extracted the HOG descriptors as follows

```
int i;      
string imgname, index;

HOGDescriptor hog (Size(64,64), Size(16,16), Size(8,8), Size(8,8), 9, 1, -1, HOGDescriptor::L2Hys, 0.2,false, HOGDescriptor::DEFAULT_NLEVELS, false);

vector<float> pos_rec_descript;
vector<Point> locations;
size_t SizeDesc;
SizeDesc = hog.getDescriptorSize();


FileStorage fpd ("Pos_Descriptors.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);

for (i = 1; i < 415; i++) { // 2416 images in ./pos_rec
    stringstream a;
    a << i;
    imgname = "./pos_rec3/img" + a.str();
    imgname += ".png";

    Mat img = imread(imgname, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    hog.compute(img, pos_rec_descript, Size (16,16), Size (0,0),locations);
    fpd << "Descriptores" + a.str() << pos_rec_descript;

}
fpd.release();
```

And I did the same with the negative samples.

Then, I trained a SVM as follows.

```
#define POS 414
#define NEG 8520
#define TOTAL 8934 
#define DESCRIPT 1764   

float trainingData[TOTAL][DESCRIPT];
int labels[TOTAL];

fstream doc;


void set_labels(){

int i;

for (i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++){

if (i < POS) {
labels[i] = 1; 
    }

    else{
labels[i] = -1; 
}
}
return;
}

int main(int, char**)
{

FileStorage fsv ("supvec.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
FileStorage ftd ("TrainData.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
//FileStorage flm ("Labels.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
FileStorage fpd ("../HOG_descriptors/Pos_Descriptors.yml", FileStorage::READ);
FileStorage fnd ("../HOG_descriptors_neg/Neg_Descriptors.yml", FileStorage::READ);

set_labels();

    // Set up training data
    vector <float> pos_D, neg_D, train_D ;
int k = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < POS+1; i++) {   
    stringstream a;
    a << i;
    fpd["Descriptores" + a.str()] >> pos_D;
    for (int j = 0; j < pos_D.size() ; j++){
    train_D.push_back(pos_D[j]);
    }
}
fpd.release();

for (int i = 1; i < NEG+1; i++) {   
    stringstream a;
    a << i;
    fnd["Descriptores" + a.str()] >> neg_D;
    for (int j = 0; j < neg_D.size() ; j++){
    train_D.push_back(neg_D[j]);
    }
}
fnd.release();

for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < DESCRIPT; j++){
    trainingData[i][j] = train_D[k]; 
    k++;
    }

}

Mat trainingDataMat(TOTAL, DESCRIPT, CV_32FC1, trainingData);
//memcpy(trainingDataMat.data, train_D.data(), train_D.size()*sizeof(float));
    Mat labelsMat(TOTAL, 1, CV_32SC1, labels);

//ftd << "trainingDataMat" << trainingDataMat;
//flm << "labelsMat" << labelsMat;  

// Train the SVM

Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
    svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
    svm->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6));

/*Ptr<TrainData> autoTrainData = TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);

ParamGrid Cgrid = SVM::getDefaultGrid(SVM::C);
ParamGrid gammaGrid = SVM::getDefaultGrid(SVM::GAMMA);
ParamGrid pGrid = SVM::getDefaultGrid(SVM::P);
pGrid.logStep = 1;   
ParamGrid nuGrid = SVM::getDefaultGrid(SVM::NU);
nuGrid.logStep = 1;
ParamGrid coeffGrid = SVM::getDefaultGrid(SVM::COEF);
coeffGrid.logStep = 1;
ParamGrid degreeGrid = SVM::getDefaultGrid(SVM::DEGREE);
degreeGrid.logStep = 1; */

cout << "Está entrenando..." << endl;   

//svm->trainAuto(autoTrainData, 10, Cgrid, gammaGrid, pGrid, nuGrid, coeffGrid, degreeGrid, false);

    svm->train(trainingDataMat, ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);

svm->save("SVM3_WS16_P0_LINEAR.yml");
```

I've tried with both LINEAR and RBF kernels (that's why you can see an autotrain part of the code commented that I used to swap between types of SVM) but none of them seems to work. Actually, they give nearly the same responses, something that makes me think that, maybe the training phase or the detection phase (code below) are ruining the whole project.

This is how I load the SVM for the HOG detector and try it over images

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv::ml;



// static void help()
// {
//     printf(
//             "\nDemonstrate the use of the HoG descriptor using\n"
//             "  HOGDescriptor::hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());\n"
//             "Usage:\n"
//             "./peopledetect (<image_filename> | <image_list>.txt)\n\n");
// }

void get_svm_detector(const Ptr<SVM>& svm, vector< float > & hog_detector );

void get_svm_detector(const Ptr<SVM>& svm, vector< float > & hog_detector )
{
// get the support vectors
Mat sv = svm->getSupportVectors();
const int sv_total = sv.rows;
// get the decision function
Mat alpha, svidx;
double rho = svm->getDecisionFunction(0, alpha, svidx);

CV_Assert( alpha.total() == 1 && svidx.total() == 1 && sv_total == 1 );
CV_Assert( (alpha.type() == CV_64F && alpha.at<double>(0) == 1.) ||
         (alpha.type() == CV_32F && alpha.at<float>(0) == 1.f) );
CV_Assert( sv.type() == CV_32F );
hog_detector.clear();

hog_detector.resize(sv.cols + 1);
memcpy(&hog_detector[0], sv.ptr(), sv.cols*sizeof(hog_detector[0]));
hog_detector[sv.cols] = (float)-rho;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
Mat img;
FILE* f = 0;
char _filename[1024];

if( argc == 1 )
{
    printf("Usage: peopledetect (People_imgs | People_imgs.txt)\n");
    return 0;
}
img = imread(argv[1]);

if( img.data )
{
    strcpy(_filename, argv[1]);
}
else
{
    f = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
    if(!f)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: the specified file could not be loaded\n");
        return -1;
    }
}  

// Load SVM

Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();

svm = cv::Algorithm::load<ml::SVM>("../SVM_Train/SVM3_WS16_P0_LINEAR.yml");


HOGDescriptor hog (Size(64,64), Size(16,16), Size(8,8), Size(8,8), 9, 1, -1, HOGDescriptor::L2Hys, 0.2,false, HOGDescriptor::DEFAULT_NLEVELS, false);

vector <float> hog_detector;
get_svm_detector (svm, hog_detector);

hog.setSVMDetector(hog_detector);
namedWindow("people detector", 1);

for(;;)
{
    char* filename = _filename;
    if(f)
    {
        if(!fgets(filename, (int)sizeof(_filename)-2, f))
            break;
        //while(*filename && isspace(*filename))
        //  ++filename;
        if(filename[0] == '#')
            continue;
        int l = (int)strlen(filename);
        while(l > 0 && isspace(filename[l-1]))
            --l;
        filename[l] = '\0';
        img = imread(filename);
    }
    printf("%s:\n", filename);
    if(!img.data)
        continue;

    fflush(stdout);
    vector<Rect> found, found_filtered, searchLocations;
vector<double> found_weights;
    double t = (double)getTickCount();
    // run the detector with default parameters. to get a higher hit-rate
    // (and more false alarms, respectively), decrease the hitThreshold and
    // groupThreshold (set groupThreshold to 0 to turn off the grouping completely).
    hog.detectMultiScale(img, found, found_weights, 0, Size(16,16), Size(0,0), 1.01, 2);
    //hog.detect(img, found, 0, Size(16,16), Size(0,0), searchLocations);
    t = (double)getTickCount() - t;
    printf("tdetection time = %gms\n", t*1000./cv::getTickFrequency());
    size_t i, j;
    for( i = 0; i < found.size(); i++ )
    {
        Rect r = found[i];
        for( j = 0; j < found.size(); j++ )
            if( j != i && (r & found[j]) == r)
                break;
        if( j == found.size() )
            found_filtered.push_back(r);
    }
    for( i = 0; i < found_filtered.size(); i++ )
    {
        Rect r = found_filtered[i];
        // the HOG detector returns slightly larger rectangles than the real objects.
        // so we slightly shrink the rectangles to get a nicer output.
        r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
        r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.7);
        r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.07);
        r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.7);
        rectangle(img, r.tl(), r.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2);
    imshow("people detector", img);
    waitKey(0);        
}
    //imshow("people detector", img);
//string imgname = "./Responses/Win_Stride16_4.png";
//imwrite(imgname, img);
    int c = waitKey(0) & 255;
    if( c == 'q' || c == 'Q' || !f)
        break;
}
if(f)
    fclose(f);
return 0;
}
```

I have checked all dimensions for the descriptors, every Mat seems to be ok. But at the time I use detectMultiScale, it shows things like this:

[Image 1: It's strange because is missing lots of detections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WGWa.png)

[Image 2: Here I realized there was a kind of pattern with this 4 rects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLj8t.png)

My problem is that no matter what I change (descriptors, Kernel, winStride and Padding in detectMultiScale), there is always very similar responses, and nothing indicates that there is a correct detection there.

I'm not very sure about how I'm giving the support vectors to HOG, but is the only way I found to do it (found it in one of the post from StackOverflow).

If any of you has any idea of what is going on here, and why the responses are not changing from one configuration to another, I would be greatly thankfull. This code is giving me headaches since weeks now. I've been changing parametres on fucntions, on HOG, changing Kernels, trying different set of images, but nothing seems to give great changes on the final result.